# Why is not the navigation buttons showing under the curtain, when the images are?

Tags: html, css

Hope you all are doing well!

I'm working on a platform for a digital art exhibition, where we want a curtain to slide aside and reveal the images.
I've used this example code for creating the curtain effect:
https://css-tricks.com/creating-css-sliding-door-effect/
And for the carousel of images, I've used this example code:
https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/gRJWqm
Since I'm totally blind, CSS is a little challenging for me because it is a little difficult to test things out myself. :)

I've been told that the pictures show as they should when the curtain slides out to the sides, but the buttons to change pictures is not showing.
I'm not sure why, because both the images and the buttons is included in the "curtain__content" div.

I wonder if anyone maybe could look a little bit at the code and tell me what I need to do to make the buttons show up as they should?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my style:

```
<style>
body {
background-color: aliceblue;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.carousel {
  padding: 20px;
  perspective: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.carousel > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.carousel figure {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.carousel figure img {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 0px;
}
.carousel figure img:not(:first-of-type) {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.carousel nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
.carousel nav button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #333;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.curtain {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
}
.curtain__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.curtain__wrapper input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.curtain__wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.curtain__panel--left {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.curtain__wrapper input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.curtain__panel--right {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
.curtain__panel {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  z-index: 2;
}
.curtain__panel--left {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.curtain__panel--right {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.curtain__content {
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
.curtain__content img {
  width: 50%;
}

</style>
```

And here is the HTML in the body tag:

```
<div class="curtain">
  <div class="curtain__wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    
    <div class="curtain__panel curtain__panel--left">
      <h1>Click to reveal&nbsp;</h1>
    </div> <!-- curtain__panel -->
    
    <div class="curtain__content">

<div class="carousel" data-gap="80">
    <figure style="transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(-4.71239rad);">
    <img src="projekt1.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px;">
        <img src="projekt2.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(0.785398rad);">
        <img src="projekt3.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(1.5708rad);">
        <img src="projekt4.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(2.35619rad);">
        <img src="projekt5.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(3.14159rad);">
        <img src="projekt6.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(3.92699rad);">
        <img src="projekt7.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(4.71239rad);">
        <img src="projekt8.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(5.49779rad);">
        <img src="projekt9.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(5.49779rad);">
        <img src="projekt10.png" alt="" style="padding: 80px; transform-origin: 50% 50% -899.521px; transform: rotateY(5.49779rad);">
    </figure>
    <nav>
        <button class="nav prev">Prev</button>
        <button class="nav next">Next

</button>

    </nav>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="curtain__panel curtain__panel--right">
      <h1>a special reward...</h1>
    </div> <!-- curtain__panel -->
    
  </div> <!-- curtain__wrapper -->
</div> <!-- curtain -->
```

Thanks in advance!

All the best!

Kind regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

There might be a couple of issues, which I'll talk about in the order of what I think is most likely.

### The text is the same color as background

At the moment, the button text and the background are the same color, namely `#333`. We can see this in the following two CSS declarations:

```css
.curtain__content {
  background: #333;
}

.carousel nav button {
  color: #333;
}
```

Because of that, the buttons blend in with the background.

### The buttons might be off the screen

While experimenting with cat pictures, if the images were sufficiently large then I found the nav buttons had gone off the bottom of the screen and curtain area. In other words, the pictures pushed the buttons below the viewport.

You have a couple of options depending on the desired design:

- Ensure the curtain area is large enough to fit the carousel and buttons (for instance, by not using viewport dimensions)
- Ensure the carousel resizes to fit within the screen
- Allow the buttons to overlay the carousel